# Sonar Design view is empty for a Java project using Maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm using Sonar version 3.7.2 with TeamCity 8.0.4 and sonner-ruuner 2.0
I am building a Java project using Maven.

In Sonar, the project design view is empty, the project dashboard works fine, showing different analysis results.

Is it possible I'm missing a "design" plugin? or I need configuration for Sonar in the Maven pom.xml?

Thanks,
Eyal
[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that you compiled your code before running the SonarQube analysis? Why don't you run the analysis with Maven (mvn sonar:sonar) instead of the SonarQube Runner? You don't need any additional plugin to get the Design information. They're retrieved from the compiled classes.

Comment: Hi David, sorry - I probably confused people with the SonarQube Runner. I am runing Maven's sonar:sonar. the code is being compiled - all the other metrics appear in the analysis - it's just the design window that's empty